# Steps to upgrade whole UI or Redo whole UI

Tags: user-interface

I have an old web application (in asp.net) of almost 100 pages which is compatible to IE 6 so I want to **revamp it's UI** because it gives browser compatibility issues and doesn't look cool either. Now I am confused what things should I use and in what order to **save time** and **avoid any error/flaw**. Here are some questions:

1) I am thinking of using **HTML 5** and make it responsive

2) I also heard of **Angular JS**, should I use it, if yes then where ?In my project java script and jquery both are used.

3) Should I use **MVC** ? But I am afraid it will require change of code which will lead to wastage of time. But it will make website faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using MVC would surely speed up UI changes in future - all UI-related code would be separated in view part of code. If you can afford redesigning your code (it's gonna take some time), it's probably worth that, considering future maintenance.

If you want to create a good, responsive UI, according to modern standards - maybe have a look at Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) framework, or similar solutions (such as Foundation - http://foundation.zurb.com/)